# Retaining HTML Tags in XML Content SAX Parser Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am using python's xml.sax library to parse XML content. I Have HTML tags withing some tags of my XML file. Lets say for eg:

```
<Car>
<Color> Blue</Color>
<Size> 1500 </Size>
<Description><p>This is <b>new  in the market</b></p></Description>
</Car>
```

So what I am currently getting is

```
Color :   Blue  
Size  :   1500
Description : <
Description : p
Description : >
Description : This is 
Description : <
Description : b
Description : >
Description : new in the market
.... and so on.
```

What I want is it to return :

```
Description - <p>This is <b>new in the market</p>
```

The file is very large so I cant manually have The HTML tags inside CDATA
Moreover I need to display all the contents in the file,Is there a way to get over this?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a state variable that you set when you enter the Description node and key off of that to handle the internal markup the way you want. Clear the state when you leave.

Comment: I will try that and let you know, I have also thought of another solution which might just work. One issue is that I dont know how many of XML tags internally have HTML content, so this is not just the case for Description Tag